# UIScrollView zoomscale in landscape and portrait mode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm having some problems with the zoomscale on my scrollview in landscape mode. I want my image to scale perfectly when i put my iphone in landscape. I have the zoomscale on my scrollview working fine when i'm loading my image in portrait mode, but when i put it to landscape, it wont change the scale, unless I go back to the tableview and put the iphone in landscape, and then load the image.

Any help apriciated!

I've tried using such as:

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice .currentDevice().orientation))
    {
        scrollView.zoomScale = 0.50
    }


    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice .currentDevice().orientation))
    {
        scrollView.zoomScale = 0.25

    }
```

This is how it looks like when I load the image in portrait mode:

[image: This is how]

This is how it looks like when i rotate the iphone from portrait mode while having the picture open(I want it to be as the image below):

[image]

This is how it looks like when i load the image in landscape mode:

[image]

Comment: Do you listen for orientation change event? Like `UIDevice.currentDevice(). beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add a orientation change listener:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "deviceDidRotate", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

And then implement `deviceDidRotate` method:

```
func deviceDidRotate(){

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)){            
        scrollView.zoomScale = 0.50
    }

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)){
        scrollView.zoomScale = 0.25
    }

}
```

Comment: Can I add this in my viewcontroller? Because it gives me a thread 1: signal SIGABART

Comment: On which line you get an error, what is this error saying? 

Add `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver..` in `viewDidLoad` and in `viewDidDisappear` add `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)`

Comment: It worked, but I when I now load the image from the tableview in landscapemode, the image loads all zoomed out, as if it was in portrait mode. Can't figure out why?